# View websocket traffic in chrome developer tools with React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket

I'm using the WebSocket support available for React Native as documented here: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network.html

My problem is, I have no way to monitor the actual incoming/outgoing websocket traffic in chrome developer tools. I know for certain in one case, that a remote server is closing my websocket connection, but because of probably a bug I introduced in my code, the error callback is not being triggered.

Is there a way to get more debug information in chrome developer tools for React Native websockets?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, sorry. The short answer is that React Native sends all network traffic through the native platform's network apis, which is why they cannot be inspected in dev tools. So, the only way for you to spy on your network traffic is to use a 3rd party proxy such as...

- [CharlesProxy](https://www.charlesproxy.com/)
- [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)

For more information, see [Network layer in React Native by Kureev Alexey](https://medium.com/dailyjs/network-layer-in-react-native-eec841f11861)